# Preventing duplicate applications/profiles of same person?

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, web-applications

I have a form which accepts in data of users name, email, sin number, location, etc.. But the problem i'm having is one of our data entry person has created duplicates of same person with slightly changed data such as phone number. I know i can put primary key on sin number since its unique but some people don't or bring in with them when filling out the application. And i do have Ids for every row which is unique no problems with that. So what techniques can i implement to prevent this from happening?

Or should I check for matching data and give a warning back such like "Warning: Might be Duplicate Entry! Matching Data. 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Location'.

If my question doesn't make sense please ask me for what you might need to help me as i'm puzzled myself.

Comment: Use unique keys to enforce data integrity.

Comment: @Phylogenesis yes i can put unique keys but most people aren't required to enter email, sin number etc. and we had some people with same names living in same building once which is rare but it did come up.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UNIQUE INDEXES instead of keys as it allows multiple NULL values on a row but I think checking for duplicates on the code is also a good idea as you can make more helpful error messages or even ask for confirmation on the cases you just think it can be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a validation in your form that check if the values that match with the rows you already have in your database. As you said, it could be with the First Name, Last Name, Email and Location fields.

Since there may be people with the same name living in a close area, you could extend the 'Location' field scope to be more specific, like a full address or something like that.